# Decimal pattern regex point not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have a decimal pattern using `regex` and it works fine in Firefox but not in IE. The point of the numeric keyboard does not work.

```
patternDecimal = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{1,2}(\.{1}([0-9]{0,1}))?$/);
```

I apply it on the input by the following way:

```
$("#inputID").allowedChars({
            "allowAlpha" : false,
            "allowAccents" : false,
            "otherChars" : '.',
            "pattern" : patternDecimal
        });
```

Comment: if you want to create a regex using the constructor pattern, put in quotation

Comment: How does your code ever interact with the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Put the argument in quotation marks when using the constructor to create a regex.

```
var patternDecimal = new RegExp('^[0-9]{1,2}(\.{1}([0-9]{0,1}))?$/');
```

Comment: why not use just the regex literal. and what are you testing for specifically? i can help you if give more insight into what you want to test for, decimals?